# Setting a custom RGB background color in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds

I believe I've correctly followed the manual in defining a custom background color in the example below.     But as the example shows, the background color is black rather than an extremely pale beige.    Could anybody advise what I'm doing wrong please?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\definecolor{MyBackground}{RGB}{1.0000    0.9451    0.6549}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=MyBackground}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hullo world
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\definecolor{MyBackground}{rgb}{1.0000,0.9451,0.6549}`. `RGB` model values are integers between 0 and 255, while `rgb` use reals between 0 and 1.

Comment: @LeoSimon and pay attention, that there should be `,` between the numbers.

Comment: @Ignasi Do you want to answer?

Comment: Don't think there's anything to answer, is there?      I switched from RGB to rgb and added commas and everything worked as I wanted!     I don't know how to accept a commment as an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code contains two little mistakes. First of all, commas are missing between values. And second, `RGB` model is defined with values between 0 and 255, while `rgb` model uses values between 0 and 1. Therefore, if

```
\definecolor{MyBackground}{RGB}{1.0000    0.9451    0.6549}
```

is replaced with

```
\definecolor{MyBackground}{rgb}{1.0000,0.9451,0.6549}
```

or

```
\definecolor{MyBackground}{RGB}{255,241,167}
```

everything will work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\definecolor{MyBackground}{rgb}{1.0000,0.9451,0.6549}
 %\definecolor{MyBackground}{RGB}{255,241,167}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=MyBackground}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hullo world
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```