# RGB color changed between .tex and .pdf (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, color

I am looking to insert a rectangle using the RGB(217,217,87) color. This color looks like [image: good RGB]

I use it with TikZ that way `{rgb:red,217;green,217;blue,87}`

However, when generating the PDF, I get this color output [image: wrong color]

**Why did the color change between the .tex file and the output PDF ?**

Full code if needed. The main.tex here is

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
%main.tex contains :
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{subfiles}
%\usetikzlibrary{babel} %Résouds les incompatbilités babel/pgfgantt
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc} %Pour les positionnement absolus sur les couvertures

\graphicspath{{../res/img/}{res/img/}}

%\newcommand{\utbmyellow}[0]{{rgb:red,217;green,217;blue,87}}
%\newcommand{\utbmpurple}[0]{{rgb:red,128;green,92;blue,139}}

\newcommand{\drawabsoluterect}[3]{
\draw [draw=#1,fill=#1]($(current page.north west)+(0cm,#2)$) rectangle 
($(current page.north west)+(\paperwidth,#3)$);
}

\newcommand{\frontcover}[0]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%Dessine l'image en haut (Hauteur 9cm)
\drawabsoluterect{red}{0cm}{-9cm}

%Dessine le label UTBM (Hauteur 0.8cm)
%\draw [draw=black,fill=black]
    %   ($(current page.north west)+(-0cm,-9.8cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.north west)+(\paperwidth,-9cm)$);
    \drawabsoluterect{black}{-9cm}{-9.8cm}

%Dessine le rectangle violet (Hauteur 2.8cm)
    \drawabsoluterect{{rgb:red,128;green,92;blue,139}}{-9.8cm}{-12.6cm}

%Ajoute le nom du projet

%Dessine le rectangle gris (Hauteur 0.95cm)
\drawabsoluterect{gray}{-12.6cm}{-13.55cm}

%Ajoute le label de l'UV
%Dessine le rectangle jaune (Hauteur 12.5cm)
\drawabsoluterect{{rgb:red,217;green,217;blue,87}}{-13.55cm}{-26.05}

%Ajoute le nom du stagiaire
%Ajoute le nom de la société
%Ajoute l'adresse de la société
%Ajoute le nom du tuteur
%Ajoute le nom du suiveur
%Dessine le logo UTBM en bas à droite
%Dessine le logo entreprise en bas à gauche
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\frontcover
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304009/setting-a-custom-rgb-background-color-in-beamer/312150#312150

Comment: Yes, thanks, it solved it. This question didn't come up while searching for RGB problems with TikZ. You should post it as an answer, or just wait for it to close with duplicate votes