# Defined color not working in tcolorbox

Tags: color, tcolorbox

I am using `xcolor` to define two custom colors and try to implement them in my `tcolorbox` boxes. 
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{3,78,170}
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{255,243,212}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=myblue, colback=myred, toprule=1pt, bottomrule=0.5pt, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, arc=0pt]
TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTE
TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
\end{tcolorbox}

\textcolor{myred}{Test?}

\end{document}
```

But there is no text visible. Also

Comment: `rgb` only accepts values between 0 and 1. Try with `RGB` instead.

Comment: I swear I just copy and pasted my color definitions from another working document... But that was the answer.

Comment: @leandriis Can you convert your comment into a response?

Comment: @AndréC: done. Tanks for reminding me.

Comment: Not duplicated, but similar problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304009/1952

Answer (score 4):

According the the `xcolor` documentation,

[image]
the `rgb` color model only accepts values between 0 and 1. The `RGB` color model on the other hand accepts integers between 0 and 255, so swithing your definitions to

```
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{3,78,170}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{255,243,212}
```

gives you the desired result.